# Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта. Работа с таймером

Tags: c#, таймер

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Для кнопки ПРАВИЛА ИГРЫ
    {
        MessageBox.Show("...");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//для кнопки НАЧАТЬ ИГРУ
    {
        button1.Visible = false;
        button2.Visible = false;
        button3.Visible = true;
        button4.Visible = true;
        button5.Visible = true;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//для кнопки НОВИЧОК
    {
        button3.Visible = false;
        button4.Visible = false;
        button5.Visible = false;
        AddButtons(3);
        timer();
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//для кнопки ЛЮБИТЕЛЬ
    {
        button3.Visible = false;
        button4.Visible = false;
        button5.Visible = false;
        AddButtons(4);
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//для кнопки ПРОФИ
    {
        button3.Visible = false;
        button4.Visible = false;
        button5.Visible = false;
        AddButtons(5);
    }
    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//кнопка СДАТЬСЯ
    {
        button1.Visible = true;
        button2.Visible = true;
        button3.Visible = false;
        button4.Visible = false;
        button5.Visible = false;
        button6.Visible = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                Controls.Remove(b[i, j]);//УДАЛЕНИЕ ВСЕХ КНОПОК для метода ""AddButtons""
            }
        }
    }
    public Button[,] b = new Button[5, 5];
    public void AddButtons(int k)//метод по созданию кнопок соответсвенно: 3x3//4x4//5x5
    {
        int k2 = k * k;
        int x = 20, y = 20, q = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
            {
                b[i, j] = new Button
                {
                    Location = new Point(x, y),
                    Size = new Size(70, 70),
                    Visible = true,
                };
                Controls.Add(b[i, j]);
                x = x + 90;
            }
            q = x;
            x = 20;
            y = y + 90;
        }
        button6.Location = new Point(q / 2 - 70, y);
        button6.Visible = true;
        Random r = new Random();//добавляем чила в кнопки
        int[] a = new int[k2];
        a[0] = r.Next(1, k2 + 1);
        for (int i = 1; i < k2; i++)
        {
            a[i] = r.Next(1, k2 + 1);
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                while (a[i] == a[j])
                {
                    a[i] = r.Next(1, k2 + 1);
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
        int l = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
            {
                b[i, j].Text = Convert.ToString(a[l]);
                l++;
            }
        }
    }
    private void timer()
    {
        timer1.Interval = 3000;
        timer1.Start();
        timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                b[i, j].BackColor=Color.Black;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}
[image: Error]

Comment: Скинул весь код, трудно предположить где ошибка. (Новичок в программирвании)

Comment: тут всё понятно. Вы создаете массив 5х5, но заполняете его не весь (например, если у вас есть вызов `AddButtons(3)`, то вы заполните только первые 9 элементов массива). `b[i,j].BackColor=Color.Black;` == > `if (b[i,j]!=null) b[i,j].BackColor=Color.Black;`

Comment: И `taimer1.Stop()` где нибудь есть? Не исключено что и нет, так-же `timer1.Dispose()` если это таймер из Threading. И каждый вызов функции `timer()` вы ей добавляете один и тот же калбек, что есть некрасиво.

Comment: В чем [разница](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/953866/220553)?